# SQL Server. Select date range query

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'd like to got a select query: 
I have two columns - NUMBER (= row_number() ) and ActionTime (datetime)
Column "Result" - this is what I need to get.

How to get result:

1. take the first line , if there are rows in which no more than 10 seconds from the current , enumerate its - 1
2. take the following unnumbered line  and repeat step 1

See an example:

```
NUMBER         ---   ActionTime     ---   Result
1           2016-04-15 15:43:58.387              1
2           2016-04-15 15:44:09.413              2
3           2016-04-15 15:44:20.470              3
4           2016-04-15 15:44:26.520              3
5           2016-04-15 15:44:32.567              4
6           2016-04-15 15:44:35.600              4
7           2016-04-15 15:44:38.657              4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in SQL Server 2012+ by using `LAG()` to find where new groups start and then a cumulative sum:

```
select e.number, e.actiontime,
       sum(case when prev_at > dateadd(second, 10, actiontime)
                then 0 else 1
           end) over (order by actiontime) as Result
from (select e.*, lag(actiontime) over (order by actiontime) as prev_at
      from example e
     ) e;
```

In earlier versions, you can do something similar using `outer apply`, but the performance is generally not quite as good.